# If $\mu$ is nonatomic and $\nu\ll\mu$, than $\nu$ is nonatomic .

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let $\nu$ and $\mu$ be two probability measures on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ such that $\nu\ll\mu$. If $\mu$ has no atoms than $\nu$ has no atoms. I want to show this assertion by contradiction.

So if $\nu$ has atoms, it means that there exists a set $M\in\mathcal{F}$ such that $\nu(M)>0$ and for any measurable subset $N\subset M$ with $\nu(N)<\nu(M)$, the set $N$ has $\nu$-measure zero. Now, if $\nu(M)>0$ than $\mu(M)>0$, but $\mu$ is nonatomic so there exist a measurable subset $S\subset M$ with $\mu(S)<\mu(M)$ such that $\mu(S)>0$...

I'm stuck, I can't get to a contradiction :(

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Radon-Nikodym Theorem we can write $\nu (E)=\int_E fd\mu$. Suppose $C$ is an atom of $\nu$. Let $A=C\cap \{f>0\}$. Check that $A$ ia also an atom of $\nu$.

Since $\nu (A) >0$ we also have $\mu (A) >0$. There is a mesurable set $B \subseteq A$ with  $0<\mu (B)<\mu(A)$. Can you finish the proof by checking that  that $0<\int_B fd\mu <\int_A fd\mu $ (which means $0<\nu (B)<\nu(A)=\nu (C)$?

Comment: First observe that $\nu(B)=\int_B f d\mu>0$ because $\mu(B)>0$ and $B\subset C\cap \{f>0\}$, so $f>0$. Now I have to show that $\nu(A)-\nu(B)>0$.  $$\nu(A)-\nu(B)=\int f(1_A-1_B)d\mu=\int_{A\backslash B}f d\mu>0$$ because $\mu(A\backslash B)=\mu(A)-\mu(B)>0$ and $A\backslash B\subset A$.

Comment: @MathLover That is perfect.

Comment: Also I tried to prove that $A$ is an atom of $\nu$ but I couldn't do it. I showed that $0<\nu(C)=\nu (C\cap \{f>0\})+\nu (C\cap \{f=0\})=\nu (C\cap \{f>0\})=\nu(A)$, but then I don't know how to demonstrate that a measurable subset $D\subset A$ with $\nu(D)<\nu(A)$ is such that $\nu(D)=0$.

Comment: @MathLover $D \subseteq A, \nu (D)<\nu(A)$ implies $D \subseteq C$ and $\nu (D)<\nu(C)$ (because $\nu (A)=\nu (C)$), Since $A$ is an atom for $\nu$ this implies $\nu (D)=0$.

Comment: Oh... I'm so stupid! Thank you very much!